# Azure Functions VS Code debug error: Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, debugging, azure-functions

I have Azure Functions project based on Node.js. When I press F5 to run, the Terminal is showing an error. PFB the error messager and screenshot. This is also blocking the control from hitting the breakpoint.

**Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, in `local.settings.json`, I set the value of `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT` property  to 1 (previously it was higher- 10)

```
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT": 1
```